# c# extendend interface implementation call through child not parent class

Tags: c#, interface, visual-studio-2013, extends

I have an interface called IDbsQuery whith the function succes(data) if i extend this interface and whith the Interface IDbsQueryDelete. How can i implement it as IDbsQueryDelete.Succes() instead of IDbsquery.succes()?

```
interface IDbsQueryReader<T> : IDbsQuery
{
    void Success(object clientReference, IEnumerable<T> data);
}

interface IDbsAllQuery : IDbsQueryReader<DbsProduct>
{
    void Success(object clientReference, IEnumerable<DbsProduct> data);
}

void IDbsQueryReader<DbsProduct>.Success(object clientReference, IEnumerable<DbsProduct> data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

instead of

```
void IDbsAllQuery.Success(object clientReference, IEnumerable<DbsProduct> data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Some of my classes will need to use queries whith the except same interface. Do i need to copy all of those with the function instead of simply extending?

Comment: I don't get the scenario. Could you please elaborate? Maybe a class diagram can help. Keep in mind that interfaces are not for code reuse. However, you could use extension methods (mixin inheritance).

Comment: I got different queries that do different things. A single session could ask for multiple ones. For example a productinfo session calls a DbsSingleProduct query and a DbsProductAncestors query. Up until now these used the same interface (IDbsQueryReader) to return their list of products. But the session that implements the interface won't know which one calls. So i created an interface that extends the IDbsQueryReader so it could called through that to differentiate like you do when you extend a class.

Square extends shape. shape has function NumberOfSides(). Square.NumberofSides()

Comment: Then why does the session implement `IDbsQuery`? It should have two objects of that type. If at all, it should be a query that returns the combined result of its children.

Comment: Not entirely certain what you mean. The session needs to start a query to the database, this happens async. The result is returned to the query who sends it to the session through the interface. First it needs to get the productInfo and then it gets the related info, like ancestors and/or children.

Comment: So the session does not implement `IDbsQuery`?

Comment: It implements IDbsAllQuery which extends IDbsQueryReader which extends IDbsQuery if that is what you mean.
So it also implements IDbsQueryReader.Succes().

Comment: In my understanding, a query reader is totally different than a query. I think you might need to revise your architecture. Is it really necessary for `IDbsAllQuery` to have a second `Sucess()`? It already inherits it from `IDbsQueryReader<DbsProduct>`.

Comment: The one in reader needs to be removed and thats my problem. because if i just use the one in reader than the session wont know how to differentiate multiple queries.

Comment: As I said, I would implement something like `class Session { IDbsQuery singleProductQuery; IDbsQuery productAncestorQuery; void Success(...) { singleProductQuery.Success(...); productAncestorQuery.Success(...); } }`.